# php download file

Tags: php, file, download

Hi i'm trying to download a file from the file  "upload". I'm using thin cobe but the result is  "I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist"

here is my call

```
<a href="download.php?filename=<?php $row4['Arxeio'] ?>">Click here
to Download the File</a>
```

and download.php

```
<?php  session_start();

$filename = $_GET['filename'];

$download_path = './upload/';

if(eregi("\.\.", $filename)) die("I'm sorry, you may not download that file.");

$file = str_replace("..", "", $filename);
// Make sure we can't download .ht control files. if(eregi("\.ht.+", $filename)) die("I'm sorry, you may not download that file.");

// Combine the download path and the filename to create the full path to the file. $file = '$download_path$filename';

// Test to ensure that the file exists. 
if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");
// Extract the type of file which will be sent to the browser as a header
$type = filetype($file); // Get a date and timestamp $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); $time = time(); // Send file headers header("Content-type: $type"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0'); // Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: `eregi()` = no, `preg_match()` = yes. But `strpos()` would do the job you are doing above. And it seems to me that what you actually wanted was `basename()` anyway. Just an FYI ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML, you need to `echo` the filename for it to be written to output:

```
<a href='download.php?filename=<?php echo $row4['Arxeio']; ?>'>Click here to Download the File</a>
```

When receiving the filename in PHP, you must validate it against directory traversal attacks. Verify that it contains no `/` or `..`.  You have a rudimentary test with `eregi()` ([which is deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php), by the way), but it can be done simply with `strpos()`.

```
if (strpos($filename, "..") >= 0 || strpos($filename, "/") >= 0) {
  // Error! don't permit file download
}
```

Review [PHP's documentation on NULL byte attack protection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php) as well.

Better though, would be to compare the `$filename` against a whitelist of valid filenames for download:

```
if (in_array($filename, array('file1.jpg', 'file2.txt', 'file3.mov',...)) {
  // Ok, send the file.
}
else {
  // Invalid file
}
```

Comment: The OP actually did sort of validate the filename, just not very well (`eregi()`), but any attempt is better than none I suppose...